# Drag & Drop pre-established elements in a Java Form Applications

Tags: java, swing

I want to be able to drag & drop elements in running time with netbeans(Java).
Fo example: I'll have elements as Texboxt,Button,Labels,ComboBox,Panel, Listbox...etc
and I want to drag as many elements as I want, and this elements could be like my toolbox en my application.

My profesor was telling me that I could use Jgraph to do this functionality another thing that he mentioned me was that I could search for a Drag and drop library or framework. for example like in this website, [1](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/431/idek.png): http://cacoo.com

[image http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/431/idek.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/431/idek.png)

Edit: I added this image of an idea. Imagine this is your own editor, and it has its own elements, like shown in the toolbox. What I want is to drag those elements and drop them to the design area, like an IDE; that is my basic challenge rigth now. Also, I  wonder if I could do this functionality with `JGraph` library or another framework that someone knows about it.

Obviously when I click the run button another window will pop up with the elements.

Comment: How can I Drag & Drop as many elements as I want while my program is running?????

Comment: See [*Introduction to DnD*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html).

Comment: I added an image to see what I want to do, because I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: See also [*The NetBeans Platform*](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/).

Comment: Use the GraphEditor example in JGraph that already demonstrates DnD? https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/tree/master/examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing